# Apple Remote Desktop help?

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I have an issue with Apple Remote Desktop and am posting here as a last resort. About 10 hours spent trying to find a solution. Looking for those with more information on the matter. Errors occurring: "viewer and server are incompatible", "Unable to communicate". Attempting to connect via VNC.

Local (Home) Computer: Macbook Pro 2012 running macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (Unable to be updated to Big Sur due to the machine being too out of date)
Remote (Work) Computer: Macbook Pro 2018 running macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

I updated the remote computer yesterday to hopefully fix this issue. It was originally having the same issues with Catalina.

Expected result: Able to connect.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Can you help us out here a bit by removing the narrative and boiling it down to just the essentials?  Please focus on the core topic (Apple Remote Desktop), the symptoms and what you expect the results to be.  Bringing in the oddities of other software is making things confusing.  I know it's frustrating when you want to get your work done, but to help you, we need to know what's happening, not that's you've spent a lot of time looking for a solution to a problem you didn't get around to describing.

Comment: @Allan udpated.

Comment: Much better!  Now..what did you try? What version of ARD are you running on each machine?  You were having this issue with Catalina..what were the issues there?  As an aside (can be answered in comments) why upgrade to Big Sur on a work machine? I always advise against immediately using a "dot zero" release when it's used for work.  Why?  The issue's you're running into prevents you from working.